# Indexed db of Outlook 2013 elemets keeps being deleted randomly every couple days

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, search-indexing

I'm at the end with my wits. I have got a destop client where Outlook 2013 keeps deleting it indexed db every couple days randomly.

I set it up so that Windows keeps only indexing the .ost (It's an Exchange Mail) currently in use. It indexes all Elements, and works just fine for a couple of days, then out of nowhere the indexed db is deleted and Outlook keeps re-indexing everything in .ost again.

This is a problem, since this is a PC in sales where the user heavily relies on Emails sent and received.

What's going on here?

Comment: Outlook keeps disappering from Indexing Options? Does Outlook search return no results?
What’d your account type? Exchange, POP or IMAP?

Comment: Indexing issues can be caused by many aspects, you can check the reply from Steve in this thread discussed in TechNet forum: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c2441a8-359f-4961-8524-e7a6572b26a6/keep-having-to-rebuild-search-index?forum=outlook

Comment: Outlook returns no results, indexed elements are set to 0 when checked. Account Type, as in the op: Exchange

Comment: Do you have cached Exchange mode enabled? Have you rebuilt index or recreated ost file as mentioned in the link above?